# What is this blank white box in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin

From startup in pgAdmin 4, there is a large white box with no text or buttons on it centered over the screen in the browser.

I'm using firefox, but also tried Chrome, same result, large white window of some sort.

I can drag it out of the way but haven't found a way to close it

Is there a way to get rid of it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried the `Esc` key?

Comment: no, but just tried it, no effect.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem after un update,

I had to go to `file > reset layout`

Comment: @RajeshS PgAdmin > file > reset layout is the solution!

Comment: while I haven't had a chance to try Sebastien's suggestion, I see no reason that his solution is not an answer.

Comment: @RajeshS this seems to be an good answer, even it it's short.

Answer (score 3):

At risk of having this deleted, the solution I ultimately went with was to use [the DBeaver database tool](https://dbeaver.io/) instead :)

It's a local application instead of run through the web browser as pgadmin4 is.

There is no floating white box anywhere to be found.

Comment: Please update this answer to follow the guidelines for software recommendations provided [here](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/911683).

Comment: Normally this kind of comment is not really welcome as it doesn't address the question. In the case of PGAdmin 4, I absolutely will make an exception.

Answer (score 1):

With the pgAdmin 4.10

`File -> Reset Layout`
works.

May be fixed in future versions